# How to execute Action method on click through scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my app I have a button. By clicking this button I want to execute an action method.

This action method does not have any view.
My requirement is: "call this action method in on click event"

How can I execute the the method on the click event?

my Onclick event is

```
$('#Delete').click(function () {

          @*  @(Url.Action("Delete", new { id="cera123"}))*@
            $.ajax({
                url: '@(Url.Action("Delete", new { id="cera123"}))',

                type: "GET",
                success:function () {


                    alert('deleted');

                }



            });
```

my action method is

```
 public ActionResult Delete(string id)
    {
        obj.EmpLi.RemoveAll(x => x.EmployeeId == id);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", obj);
    }
```

delete action is performed but i an see the result after  voluntarily refreshing the page even though i gave RedirectToAction("Index")

thanks

Comment: You can use $.ajax() to call any action methods, you want.

Comment: my requirement i need to call from script  thanks

Comment: essentially you are doing an AJAX call to the action method on the controller (or a method in ASP.NET)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#yourbutonId").click(function(){ 
        $.get("/controller/action/id",function(data){
            //data is what your action return
        });
    });
});
```

nilesh is right $.ajax is js,and $.get is sample use base on $.ajax
or $.post
to make these code work,you should ref jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

### Some background info...

If you come from the webforms and code-behind world is common to you that an HTML element calls a script in the code, but actually what asp.net webforms does is an http call to the script on the server. If you had an `updatepanel`, asp.net webforms would have done the same call via ajax.

That's the reason why in asp.net webforms the elements have the preceding `asp:` on their branded `html` tags. That way asp.net can convert their branded elements to real HTML elements.

### The answer

The only way to execute the code of an `action` from an HTML element on-click event in  asp.net MVC is by calling the URL that gets to that method. Either via ajax or by a request from the browser, an http request needs to be done.

With javascript you can listen when an element's on-click event is fired and then do some logic. If you're using jquery you can use the `$.ajax()` or `$.get()` methods to make a call to your action URL.